# Missing ; after for loop initializer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple `for` loop and I keep getting this error:

> missing ; after for loop initializer.

I can't seem to figure out why. `cleari` is an array of input fields. So, I'm basically trying to take each field in the array, and reset it:

```
var cleari = document.getElementById(rowNum).getElementsByTagName('input');
for (cleari) {
    cleari.parentNode.innerHTML = cleari.parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is of the convention `for(a;b;c)`

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  {
     alert(i);
}
```

A **`while`** loop is of the convention `while(a)`

For example:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 10){
    alert(i);
    ++i;
}
```

---

So for your example what you can do is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cleari.length; i++){
    cleari[i].parentNode.innerHTML = cleari[i].parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: See also [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and 
[`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have been looking for the for...in loop:

```
var clearis = document.getElementById(rowNum).getElementsByTagName('input');

for(cleari in clearis)
{
    clearis[cleari].parentNode.innerHTML = clearis[cleari].parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

You can read more about the [for...in loop at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: It worked! I dont exactly understand it! But thats ok, ill figure it out later. thanks.